# Capture and play new media types with AVFoundation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I've got a very non-standard AVFoundation question and as a relative newbie to the iOS world I could really use some guidance from the experts out there -

I'm working on an app that lets the user record bits of audio which I need to programmatically arrange using `AVMutableComposition`.  Here's the thing, in addition to the audio track I want to capture and save accelerometer data and have it synced with the sound.  Typically AVFoundation is used for known media types like still photos, audio, and video but I was wondering whether it's feasible to capture something like accelerometer data using this framework.  This would make it much easier for me to sync the sensor data with the captured audio, especially when putting the parts together with `AVMutableComposition`.

Here is what I need to accomplish:

1. Record accelerometer data as an `AVAsset/AVAssetTrack` so I can insert it into an `AVMutableComposition`
2. Allow for playback of the accelerometer data in a custom view alongside the audio it was recorded with
3. Save the `AVMutableComposition` to disk, including both audio and accelerometer tracks.  It would be nice to use a standard container like Quicktime

For part 1 & 3 I'm looking at using `AVAssetReader`, `AVAssetReaderOutput`, `AVAssetWriter`, `AVAssetWriterInput` classes to capture from the accelerometer but without much experience with Cocoa I'm trying to figure out exactly what I need to extend.  At this point I'm thinking I need to subclass `AVAssetReaderOutput` and `AVAssetWriterInput` and work with `CMSampleBuffers` to allow the conversion between the raw accelerometer data and an `AVAsset`.  I've observed that most of these classes only have a single private member referencing a concrete implementation (i.e. `AVAssetReaderInternal` or `AVAssetWriterInputInternal`).  Does anyone know whether this a common pattern or what it means for writing a custom implementation?

I haven't yet given part 2 much thought.  I'm currently using an `AVPlayer` to play the audio but I'm not sure how to have it dispense sample data from the asset to my custom accelerometer view.

Apologies for such an open ended question - I suppose I'm looking more for guidance than a specific solution.  Any gut feelings as to whether this is at all possible with AVFoundations architecture?

Comment: what do you mean by playback of accelerometer data...how are you going to display the data?

Comment: I'll have a custom UIView that will be rendering something based on the accelerometer playback.I'd like to handoff the audio and accelerometer tracks as an `AVPlayerItem` to the `AVPlayer` but I'm not sure how the `AVPlayer` delegates playback or vends the actual samples.  I've thought about registering for playback notifications with `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:..` and just rendering the content then but I'm not sure that's now Apple did it with say `AVPlayerLayer`.  Or is it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a NSmutableArray and store the accelerator data plus the time code there. So when you play back you can get the time from the video player and use that look up the accelerator data in the array. Since the data is store as a time line you don't have to search the whole array. It is enough to step forward in the array and check when the time data coincide.

Comment: I'd really like to take advantage of AVFoundation's composition features and eventually write a Quicktime file with both the audio and accelerometer data interleaved.